# psql restore goes shows me the shell instead of restoring the data: how to restore with psql?

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line, psql

I'm using win 10 64bit.

I dump my data with `pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --no-owner --no-privileges --dbname=crm_db --schema=public --exclude-table=public.\"cmsArticle\" --host=xxx --username=xxx --port=5432 -v --file=D:\\db_backup\\dump.sql`

I got a 20GB file, now I tried to restore with: `psql -d crm_db --host=xxx.postgres.database.azure.com --username=xxx -p 5432 -v -f D:/db_backup/dump.sql`

And I see `psql: warning: extra command-line argument D:/db_backup/dump.sql`.

Solution found:

I tried to change to `psql -d crm_db --host=xxx.postgres.database.azure.com --username=xxx -p 5432 -v -f D:\\db_backup\\dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change to `psql -d crm_db --host=xxx.postgres.database.azure.com --username=xxx -p 5432 -v -f D:\\db_backup\\dump.sql`. Need to use `\\` instead of `/`. There was some post on stackoverflow saying that needs to use `/` on windows, but seems wrong.